# start and activity after and activity finishes

Tags: android, android-intent

So I am launching an update and then sending it as a message. When the message is I want it to go back to the home screen of the app. I have what I think would do that, but instead it just quickly opens the other activity then closes it and loads the home screen. How can I get the activity to return to the home screen activity upon completion of sending the message.

```
 public void send(View view)
{

    savePhoto();
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    close();
    //This activity opens and quickly closes
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send:"));
    startActivity(home);


}
```

Comment: I don't understand, if you would like to go back to previous screen after send, why call startActivity? why not finish() instead?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is startActivityForResult ([ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)):

```
private final static int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

public void send(View view) {
    ...
    startActivityForIntent(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send:"));
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //You can check for any result set from request activity
            //Set your own results using Activity.setResult(int);
            startActivity(home);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted your `onActivityResult` code, but it still returned  me to the previous activity and called the `onResume();`

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
 public void send(View view)
 {

savePhoto();
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
close();
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send:"));
Intent i=new Intent(this,Home.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
}
```